# Laravel new middleware does not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am creating simple referral system. I've finished the work, but the referral system seems to not work correctly, most likely because of middleware. I will explain the problem more clearly.

So, here is my register controller

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $referred_by = Cookie::get('referral');

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'affiliate_id' => str_random(10),
        'referred_by'   => $referred_by
    ]);
}
```

And the middleware

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;

use Closure;

class CheckReferral
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if( $request->hasCookie('referral')) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else {
        if( $request->query('ref') ) {
            return redirect($request->fullUrl())-
    >withCookie(cookie('referral', $request->query('ref'), 30));
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I also added middleware to kernel

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckReferral::class, 
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

So, all users get the `afflitiate_id`, but none of them the `reference_by` in the database

EDIT: THE WHOLE REG CONTROLLER

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Requests; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Cookie;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data, Request $request)
{
    $referred_by = $request->cookie('referral');

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'affiliate_id' => str_random(10),
        'referred_by' => $referred_by
    ]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually very easy. \App\Http\Middleware\CheckReferral::class, should have been to the $middlewareGroups Web not $middleware.
So that the application will be able to capture referral links and store them in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your middleware is not a problem. You need to change the way you are getting the cookie in your controller:

```
protected function create(array $data, Request $request)  // Adding request as an argument.
{
    $referred_by = $request->cookie('referral');  // Notice the change here

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'affiliate_id' => str_random(10),
        'referred_by'   => $referred_by
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/invest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php on line 33

Comment: Add this line before class declaration: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is actually added here is the full register controller

Comment: Where is full register controller?

Comment: Add both of these `use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/invest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php on line 33
in RegisterController.php (line 67)

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post updated code again after you added those three lines?

Comment: Watch the main question. register controller full

Comment: After I asked you to add  
`App\Http\Requests;` and `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` you have not updated your code in question.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: unfortunately no :(

Comment: I get this error . Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/invest/vendor/laravel/framework/sr‌​c/Illuminate/Foundat‌​ion/Auth/RegistersUs‌​ers.php on line 33 in RegisterController.php (line 67)